# Create Map based on two other maps in Java

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, map-function

How can I build a map based on two others maps using Java 8 streams? Namely, I have the following map structures:

```
map1 = Map<MyModel, List<String>>();
map2 = Map<String, String>();
```

where `List<String>` values of `map1` are the identical with `String` keys in `map2`. In other words based on `map1 values` one can use it as `keys` in `map2` and get `values` from there.

So, my question is how to merge those two maps with usage of streams and lambdas techniques and build a new map which will include `MyModel as keys` and `List<Strings> as values` with no duplicates?

This what I have so far:

```
map1 = Map<MyModel, List<String>>();
map2 = Map<String, String>();

Map<MyModel, List<String>> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (v1, v2) -> v1
    )
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with transforming a `List<String> list` by looking up values form `map2` and discarding duplicates:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
.....

list.stream()
    .filter(map2::containsKey)  // make sure map2 has this key
    .map(map2::get)             // get the value
    .distinct()                 // discard duplicates
    .collect(toList());         // make new list
```

Now you just have to use the above as the value mapper  (with static imports of `Collectors` methods) to solve your problem:

```
map1.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .filter(map2::containsKey)
        .map(map2::get)
        .distinct()
        .collect(toList())
));
```

Comment: Nice answer .. very concise

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using of your suggested method shows Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context error for the `Map.Entry::getKey` and Cannot resolve method error for the `e.getValue().stream()`.

Comment: @Dozent Make sure you include static import of `toList` and `toMap`.  See https://www.ideone.com/mxeRTf

Comment: @Misha, I did it other way but with usage of your technique in stream scope. Thanks for the idea. It's accepted :D

Answer (score 1):

Below is something I thought of quickly. There may be a more efficient way to implement your requirements but it will at least give you a start.

***Code***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Map 1
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
    map1.put(2, Arrays.asList("C", "D"));

    //Map 2
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("A", "Apple");
    map2.put("B", "Banana");
    map2.put("C", "Cherries");
    map2.put("D", "Dewberries");

    Map<Integer, List<String>> collect = map1.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> {
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                        entry.getKey(),
                        entry.getValue()
                                .stream()
                                .map(map2::get)
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue));

    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

***Output***

```
{1=[Apple, Banana], 2=[Cherries, Dewberries]}
```

Comment: Using `entry.setValue` will attempt to modify the source map, which is dangerous.  And if modifying the original is acceptable, it's better to be explicit about it with `map1.replaceAll( (k,v) -> ....)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Misha .. I've edited my code to not update the existing Map.Entry and instead create and return another object.

Comment: @GarrethGolding, thanks for the response, your method also works! But as you mentioned above Misha's answer is nice and concise ;)